# Comparing to text files in java

Tags: java

I have to write a java program that compare two tables and print the the ones that are not same.
This my try, but for some reason the program do the complete opposite.

```
 public class reading_file {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        File is1 =new File("T1.txt");
        File is2 =new File("T2.txt");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(is1);
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(is2);
        while (sc1.hasNext() && sc2.hasNext()) {
            String str1 = sc1.next();
            String str2 = sc2.next();
            if (str1 != str2)
                System.out.println(str1 + "  " + str2);
        }
        while (sc1.hasNext())
            System.out.println(sc1.next() + " != EOF");
        while (sc2.hasNext())
            System.out.println("EOF != " + sc2.next());
        sc1.close();
        sc2.close();
    }
}
```

This is the tables:

```
ID Name   
1   A
26  Z
3   C
ID Name
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

And this is my output

```
1  1
A  A
26  2
Z  B
3  3
C  C
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Instead of `if (str1 != str2)` use `if (!str1.equals(str2))`

Answer (score 0):

As Karthikeyan Vaithilingam pointed out, you have used `if (str1 != str2)`. This is incorrect. Using the `!=` conditional operator compares the two `String` objects rather than their actual value, in which case your code will continue to run.

Here is a great article on `String` comparison: http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/27/string-comparison-with-equals-and-assignment-operator/